# UIcollectionview with server data

Tags: ios, json, swift, uicollectionview, delegates

iam trying to make collectionview with server data i returned data in an 
array and print it to ensure that data is returned

```
    extension ViewController : DataModelDelegate {


        func didRecieveDataUpdate(data: Data) {

            let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])

            // parse json array
            guard let jsonArray = responseJSON as? [[String: Any]]
                else {
                    return
            }
            for dic in jsonArray {
                self.listOfCategories.append(MCategories(dic))
            }
            print(self.listOfCategories[1].Name)
            print(self.listOfCategories.count)

        }
```

}

but this array returned 0 in collectionview() > int  func

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(self.listOfCategories.count)
    return listOfCategories.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cellcategory:CVC_Categories = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CVC_Categories
    cellcategory.setCategoryData(categories: listOfCategories[indexPath.row])
    return cellcategory
}
```

and i call this delegates in viewdidload()

```
 var listOfCategories = [MCategories]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    gettoken()
    self.dataModel.delegate = self
    dataModel.requestData()
    cv_categories.delegate = self
    cv_categories.dataSource = self

    }
```

Comment: You have to call `reloadData()` on the collection view at the end of `didRecieveDataUpdate`

Comment: Also try reloading the collection view in main queue DispatchQueue.main.async {}

Answer (score 1):

Once you have received the data, you need to communicate to the collection view that the data has changed. You do that by calling `reloadData()` on the collection view.

So, in your case:

```
  func didRecieveDataUpdate(data: Data) {

    ....

    OperationQueue.main.async {
      self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

add reloadData() inside this block to make it run in the main thread

```
OperationQueue.main.addOperation ({
                self.cv_categories.reloadData()
            })
```